# MIPS: Using the stack

Tags: assembly, stack, mips

I was reading in a MIPS manual that:
"Notice we use the “unsigned” version of the “add immediate” instruction because we are dealing with an address, which is an unsigned binary number. We wouldn’t want to generate an exception just because a computed address crossed over the mid-point of the memory space."

What does this mean exactly? Specifically crossing over the mid-point of the memory space.

And also, in the following code, I don't understand why it skips from 8($sp) to 20($sp). The code loads from 12($sp) and 16($sp) later but when is it doing something with these portions of memory. I was thinking possible in jal JILL, but there isn't really much explanation given.

```
addiu $sp, $sp, -24 
sw $t1, 0($sp) 
sw $t2, 4($sp) 
sw $t3, 8($sp) 
sw $ra, 20($sp) 
jal JILL
lw $ra, 20($sp) 
lw $t4, 12($sp) 
lw $t5, 16($sp) 
addiu $sp, $sp, 24
```

Comment: it is not an "unsigned addition"  it is an addition with an "unsigned overflow exception".  The addition operation itself is not aware of the interpretation of the bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumming a MIPS32 architecture, which has a 32-bit address space, the mid-point of the memory space would be address 0x80000000 (that is 2^31).
In 32-bit signed (A2-compliment) arithmetics, integers from 0 to 0x7FFFFFFF are reserved for positive numbers, where integers from 0x80000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF are reserved for negative numbers.

When you issue a signed addition, you would get an overflow exception if the result of the addition "crosses" that midpoint. But in your example, you are really dealing with memory addresses, not signed numbers... therefore the sign of the address (interpreted as a 32-bit number) is meaningless so you should use unsigned addition.

Regarding your second question, you'd have to look into the JILL procedure to see what it does... surely that procedure will store some information in `12($sp)` and `16($sp)`

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it is just to prevent an overflow exception that could possible occur due to two's complement addition. And also regarding the second question, what would be the difference between the implementation above and just adjusting the stack in JILL? Would it be much more difficult in code and conceptually?

Comment: Yes, it's just to prevent an overflow exception that may arise if the stack is located near the mid-point of the memory space. Regarding your second question, it all depends on the calling convention used to call other procedures. In your example the caller is reserving space in the stack for the called procedure to store the results, then upon returning from the caller your program uses the results and frees the stack space used. You cannot easily move that behaviour to the JILL procedure because some registers need to be preserved by the caller ($t1, $t2, $t3 and $ra)

Comment: What I meant was that you cannot easily restore the stack used by the caller in the callee because usually you don't know who the callee is. Therefore, how would you know which registers to restore and how much memory to free from the stack ? The answer is that you usually wouln't know, so its better to stick to the rule that the procedure which allocates space from stack  (and backs up information in it) is the one that frees it (and restores what needed to be backed up)